# Child categories doesn't echo if it doesn't contain at least a post

Tags: categories

I'm looping though child categories of a given parent, but what I've noticed is that it doesn't get echoed if the child category itself doesn't have any posts in relation to it. How can I echo children even though they don't have any posts?

```
    $children = get_categories(
        array( 'parent' => 923)
    );

    foreach ($children as $child) {  
        echo "<h6>Child: " . $child->name . "</h6>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) won't return terms that have no posts ([the `hide_empty` parameter is true](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/)).

This should do it:

```
$children = get_categories(
    array(
        'parent'     => 923,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);
```